# Conditional list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to gain a better understanding of how list comprehensions work.
I have the following function that returns true or false if a number is prime (which I found somewhere on the forum but cant remember where):

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

if I run:

```
[x for x in range(2, num) if is_prime(x)]
```

i get the desired result

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

in trying to convert the whole function to a list comprehension I came up with:

```
[x if not (x%2==0 and x > 2) else x for x in range (2, num) 
     for i in range(3, int(x**(1/2))+1, 2) if not (x%i==0)]
```

which produces:

```
[10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19]
```

not sure where I am going wrong and would appreciate some help.  In truth I think it is better to use the function in this case, but like I said I am trying to understand the list comprehension and its capabilities.

Comment: @Wright: that just returns odd numbers and excludes 2.  OP is also excluding numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: I'd say its too much to squeeze into a list comprehension. It's ok for practicing, but don't create something like that when anyone else has to read it.

Comment: Just for giggles I timed each version: the function `[x for x in range(2, num) if is_prime(x)]` version was **9.01 s per loop**; @Julien version (with my slight modification):  **12.8 s per loop** and @Harshit Garg version: **44.4 s per loop**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[n for n in range(2, num) if n % 2 != 0 and n > 2 and all(n % i != 0 for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))]
```

although one liner just for the sake of it is not necessarily a good thing. IMO using a prime tester function like you do is better...

NOTE: what doesn't work in your try is that you modified the logic of your outer list comprehension. You still want a structure like `[n for n in range(...) if (expression testing if n is prime)]`.

Comment: I modified it a little to include '2' in the list: `[n for n in range(2, num) if (n % 2 != 0 or n ==2) and all(n % i != 0 for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))]`.  Not sure I fully understand why the answer works, but excludes '2' but will look at it some more.

Comment: I agree the function is the better way to do it.  This is an exercise for me to try and gain a better understanding of list comprehensions.  I figure if I can understand something complex, it will help me understand the easier more appropriate uses.

Comment: Good spot, I indeed forgot to negate `n>2` to `n==2`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're making a convoluted translation.  Try simplifying the original condition so that you return "x if x==2, else x ..." as you've already done.  I'm just giving you a leading hint here; from what you've done already, I think you can figure it out.

If not, try simplifying the "else" expression so you learn the logic of that clause.  Then I'm sure you'll get it.  You're doing well.

Answer (score 0):

There are logical errors in the code above
`1/2` evaluates to 0, not to 0.5. To do that, either use 0.5 or 1/2.0 or 1.0/2

Also it does not take care of 2 as a special case. as `(for i in range(3, int(x**(1/2.0))+1, 2) if not (x%i==0))` is not executed

`for i in range(3, int(x**(1/2.0))+1, 2) if not (x%i==0)` is also a logical error as whenever this condition is true, it causes multiple entries to be added

the correct way would be

```
[x for x in range (2, num) if x == 2 or (x > 2 and x % 2 == 1 and len([i for i in range(3, int(x**(1/2.0))+1, 2) if x%i == 0 ])==0)]
```

Comment: I am in Python 3 and `(1/2)` evaluates to `0.5` for me, not sure if the issue you stated is in older version of Python, however, your answer does work